# Unity unityscript Error

Tags: loops, unity-game-engine, conditional-statements, unityscript

I have an array learnnum that looks like [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0].

I need to basically ask the user for an input Left Mouse Button or Right Mouse Button. If Left, then the values of learnnum of [i] is flipped, else nothing happens. I only do this for i=1,3,5,7. I have written the below code, but it does not work properly, instead of going for all the 4 conditions... it directly goes to 4. It seems that it is not waiting for the input conditions... Is there any way I can correct this?

```
function changeNumba(i)
{       //check1=true;
        print ("PRINTT "+check1);
                    while(!Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1") && !Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
                    {
                    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
                    {
                    check1++;
                    }
                if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2"))
                    {
                    learnednum[i]=0 ? 1 : 0;
                    check1++;
                    }
                }

}

function changelearn()
{       

        //FIRST STEP
        //if(check1)    
        if(move1==9 && check1==0)
            {changeNumba(1);

            }
        //SECOND STEP   
        if(move1==9 && check1==1)
            {changeNumba(3);

            }
        if(move1==9 && check1==2)
            {changeNumba(5);

            }
        if(move1==9 && check1==3)
            {changeNumba(7);

            }
}





var check1=0;

//1,3,5,7
function Update () {


if(move1==9)//this is just a game condition. Do not bother about it.
{
changelearn();
}

 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from looking at the unity script api:
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetButtonDown.html

you should not have a while() loop inside of your Update() method.

change changeNumba() as follows:

```
function changeNumba(i)
{
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")){
    check1++;
}
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2")){
    learnednum[i] = learnednum[i]==0 ? 1 : 0;
    check1++;
}
}
```

Comment: Exactly, update it called every frame no need to while loop you will just cause the game to slow down. Unless your goal was to only update when you're goal was to never update unless you held down the right mouse button for 9 update frames and then it would continue